# How to get data from a SearchComponent to my ListComponent in angular >2?

Tags: angular

I have 3 components:
1. Header Component;
2. Search Comp;
3. Home Comp;

Home Comp contains my list of users, Header Comp contains the Search Comp so I would like to pass my searchString to Home Comp passing between Header Comp.

I was looking for something like event emitter but I'm not able to apply it to my code.

Home Comp:

```
<div class=" container-fluid">
        /.../
    <app-search></app-search>
 </div>
```

Search Comp:

```
<div class="row no-margin">

        <div class="row no-margin row-padding">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 searchbar">
                <input type="text" class="ricerca ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse"
                       [placeholder]="placeHolder"
                       [(ngModel)]="searchname" (keypress)="searchBarKey($event)">
                <div class="searchIco"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Home Comp:

```
<div class="list">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">

            <div *cdkVirtualFor="let user of data" | ADD SOMETHING>

                <div class="box_dipendenti">
                    <div class="float_l b_max_width">
                        <h5 class="cursorHover" (click)="showModal(user)">
                            <span>{{user.firstName}} </span>
                            <span>{{user.lastName}}</span>
                        </h5>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</div>
```

At the moment I didn't add any method beacuse I don't know what to put inside.

Anyone has any advice?

Comment: You're probably going to have to create a service to share the data since the components are not nested, meaning one is not a child of the other.  Here is a stackflow that contains a stackblitz of how to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317878/how-to-set-or-pass-a-property-state-between-unnested-component-in-angular/55318104#55318104

Answer (score 0):

So there are several ways to pass data between components, depending on your component hierarchy. What I would suggest is to read through this article:

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

It covers the 4 main ways there are to share data between components, so if you're unsure of where to begin then this is where I would start. To get you rolling, passing the value of your input box in the search component to the home component would require a shared service, which is covered in the link posted.

I hope this helps!