# How to share data between components that are not related? Angular 6

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angular, typescript

I have two components, where the second changes according to the name selected in the first component.

If I select 'Bryan' in the first component my service should fetch the information regarding Bryan in the database and move to my second component since it has the function of generating the table with the information.

I tried to use the Subject class, but could not associate the emit with the return of the HTTP request that is observable.

template

```
<form class="mt-4" [formGroup]="managerForm">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let teamSale of teamSales">
    <label for="ManagerName" class="mt-2">{{ teamSale }}</label>
    <select id="ManagerName" class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="ManagerName" (change)="getAccountsByName()">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let manager of managers">
        <option *ngIf="manager.Team === teamSale" [value]="manager.Name">{{ manager.Name }}</option>
      </ng-container>
    </select>
    <hr>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

[image]

service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

import { Account } from 'src/app/models/account-model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class QuotationService {

    private urlAPI: string = 'http://localhost:9095';

    private quotationByManegerSource = new Subject<Account[]>();
    public quotationByManeger$ = this.quotationByManegerSource.asObservable();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public getAccountsByName(managerName: string): Observable<Account[]> {
        const url: string = `${this.urlAPI}/get-accounts-by-name/${managerName}`
        return this.http.get<Account[]>(url)
    }
}
```

I want, when selecting a name, the information in the database that refers to that name is passed to another component.

And let this second component listen to the changes made in the first component.

Comment: Here is an example that has a stackblitz demo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317878/how-to-set-or-pass-a-property-state-between-unnested-component-in-angular/55318104#55318104

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subject inside your service

**`messageSource: Subject<string>;`**
and instantiate inside your constructor

```
this.messageSource = new Subject<string>();
```

in your component you can do this,

```
this.yourService.messageSource.next('whatvermessage');
```

and if you want to subscribe to it, you can do

```
this.yourService.messageSource.asObservable().subscribe((value: string) => {

});
```

Comment: I created the Subject in my service, but how do I associate the value returned from the database to this Subject?

I need to issue the value returned from the database and then retrieve it in the other component.

Comment: just set the value to the subject

Comment: It gives type conflict.
How should I do this?

Comment: what is the conflict