# How to share data between non-Parent-child components

Tags: angular

I want to disable a form's submit button based on a variable that is set in app.component. The components don't have a parent child relationship. They are linked using routes.
Scenario : I want to set a true or false value based on which role is selected. Hence when the role is selected a function is called to set the Boolean value.

I tried using shared service but i am unable to retrieve the variable value in other components. I am unable to subscribe to a Boolean value.

app.component.html

```
<form #roleForm="ngForm">
    <select name="userRole" [(ngModel)]="viewSelected" (click)=SelectRole()>
      <option value="admin">Admin</option>
      <option value="layman">layman</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

app.component.ts

```
SelectRole() {
    this._studentService.onSelectRole().subscribe(data);
  }
```

service.ts

```
public viewSelected = "admin";
public buttonDisabled : boolean = true;

onSelectRole() {
    if (this.viewSelected == "admin") {
      this.buttonDisabled = true;
    } else {
      this.buttonDisabled = false;
    }
  }
```

form.component.html => this is where i am trying to use the boolean variable

```
<form [formGroup]="addForm">

  <mat-label>First Name : </mat-label>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="firstName">
  </mat-form-field>
  <br><br>
  <button [disabled]="buttonDisabled" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I kept the role in app component so that role can be selected/changed from any component. When the role is selected/changed i want to disable certain buttons based on the role. 
So how can i achieve this? Am i on the right track ? or are there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Use a service for sharing data. Check method 4 of this link https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angular/sharing-data-between-angular-components-methods

Comment: Do this: `<button [disabled]="viewSelected !== 'admin' " ...>` directly without the using the extra logic in your service. As you kept the role in app component it should be available from other components.

Comment: As other have said, you can use a service with rxjs to share data between components.  Here is a similar questions with a stackblitz example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317878/how-to-set-or-pass-a-property-state-between-unnested-component-in-angular/55318104#55318104

Comment: @Dblaze, ur suggestion helped... the button is disabled. But its disabled for all roles as i have declared viewSelected ='admin' as default value. the form has two way binding set, and i can see the value of viewSelected changing as per my selection. But the condition is not being updated in the disabled condition..

Comment: Check out my answer for detecting changes

Comment: i am using angular 7.3.0, getting this error -> Can't bind to 'readOnly' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. Do i need to import any module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic case where you can use a subject.

**app.component.ts**

```
this.roleChangeSubject$.next(role)
```

**sibling.component.ts**

```
roleSub$:Subscription<string>;
constructor(private sharedService:SharedService) {
this.roleSub$ = this.sharedService.roleChangeSubject$;
}
```

**sibling.component.html**

```
<button [disabled]="roleSub$ | async !== 'admin'"></button>
```

updating values in a variable in service does not change in the component unless that variable is an observable or a subject which listens to the value changes that happens.

usage of changeDetectorRef must be done in extreme cases not in all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular attributes `disabled` or `readonly` (for angular5+). Examples:

```
<button [disable]=="viewSelected !== 'admin' " ...>
<button [readonly]="viewSelected !== 'admin' " ...>
```

If you are facing problems that your role is changing but not updated in the button, you need [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef). This is how you inject it in your constructor and detect changes (similar to $scope.$apply in AngularJS):

```
// Inject in your constructor:
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
 ....
}


// And call this:
this.ref.detectChanges();
```